# Github pages not recognizing CSS

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages

This is my first time trying to use Github pages. I am able to to get the `index.html` to work, but the style will not. I am serving from the `master` branch `docs/` folder.

Everything works fine when I run it on my local host. Any ideas?

### File tree

[image: File tree]

### Stylesheet

[image: Stylesheet]

Tried changing my static and templated folder names to 'docs' and 'css' as I thought Github looks in specific folders for HTML and CSS files. Also looked to make sure my `href` was pointing to the right place. I'm new to this, so I may have made a mistake.

EDIT: I am using Flask, which may be causing the issue, website is still static. IDK if Flask and static contradictory.

Thanks

Comment: git is not the same as github. Check the console for errors, perhaps your css don't load for some reason

Comment: Can you reference the repo?

Comment: I believe the repository mklupar has the issue in is [this one](https://github.com/mklupar/Senior_Desgin/). The GitHub pages site is public [here](https://mklupar.github.io/Senior_Desgin/).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.